# JQuery Datepicker restrict to bi-weekly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How do I restrict the JQuery Datepicker to show only bi-weekly Saturdays. I have successfully restricted it to show only weekly but could not figure out how to make it bi-weekly. See sample code below for weekly filter that allows for Saturdays only.

```
$("#datefilter").datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
        if(date.getDay() === 6){
            return [true];
        }else{
            return [false];
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not test too much, but this should work for 1st and 3rd Saturday (5th too):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
          var dayOfMonth = date.getDate()
            if(date.getDay() === 6 && Math.floor((dayOfMonth - 1) / 7) % 2 === 0){
                return [true];
            }else{
                return [false];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And if you want 2nd and 4th, replace `0` with `1` in 2nd part of `if` condition:

`Math.floor((dayOfMonth - 1) / 7) % 2 === 1`

**UPDATE** corrected calculation, should be `(dayOfMonth - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is another option, if you anticipate needing to change to another day of the week you can seed it with a date that falls on that day:

```
function isAlternatingDay(testDate){
    var seedDay = new Date(2018,11,3);
    var daysDiff = (testDate - seedDay)/86400000;

    return daysDiff % 14 === 0;
}
```